# Total Percentage Change - Why does this work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, percentages

Algebraically this works, but I'm looking to understand **(1) why it works** and **(2) if there is a simpler formula**.

**Problem:** 
I want to get total % change over time.

**Facts:**

Example Data -

Jan 2013 - 14.29%

May 2013 - 25%

Oct 2013 - 20%

```
**Solution Methodology:**

1. Take a random baseline number to plugin: 100

2. Calculate the actual numbers:

    Jan 2013 - 14.29% Increase = 114.29

    May 2013 - 25% Increase = 142.8625

    Oct 2013 - 20% Increase = 171.435

3. Calculate Total % Difference:

    (171.435 - 100) / 100 = 71.435%

4. Plug in variables to determine formula to do this:

Baseline Number = X

A = Jan 2013 Increase % = (x)(A + 1) = (xA + x)

B = May 2013 Increase % = (xA + x)(B + 1) = (xAB + xA + xB + x)

C = Oct 2013 Increase % = (xAB + xA + xB + x)(C + 1) = (xABC + xAC + xBC + xC + xAB + xA + xB + x) = x(ABC + AC + BC + C + AB + A + B + 1)

Calculate % Change = 
(x(ABC + AC + BC + C + AB + A + B + 1) - x) / x
```

**Final Algebraic Formula =**
ABC + AC + BC + C + AB + A + B

**Other Notes**
Interestingly enough if I only looked to get the Total % Difference of May 2013 and Jan 2013 the algebraic formula becomes:
**AB + A + B**

There is a chance I'm overcomplicating this or am calling it the wrong thing.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Try not to have a lopsided view https://twitter.com/grenouf/status/724263408888107008 of algebraic experssions. It may be that you have a preference for the sum-of-products form. Try to also get used to expressing your formulas in product-of-sums form e.g. $x(A+1)(B+1)(C+1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier to understand why this works if you consider the percentage increases as decimal multiplications.

Example: starting with $100$, a $A=10\%$ increase is equivalent to $100*1.10$, where the percentage $10\%$ is divided by $100$ and added to $1$.
We add $1$ to include the **initial amount**.
When multiple interests are compounded (applied sequentially), you are simply multiplying the respective decimal values together.
Your final algebraic formula works as a result of multiplication's distributive property, but it can be written more generally as $$(\prod_{i=1}^n (A_i+1)) - 1$$
Where $A$ represents the interest rate, and $\prod$ means multiply all of the following together, for $i$ starting at $1$, and incrementing by $1$ until it reaches $n$.